# How to push local repository on master branch to remote repository's main branch?

Tags: git, github

My situation is the following. I've had a git repository set up for me by someone else, and I'm tasked with pushing to the main branch. I started a local React project on a master branch, and I want to push my code to the remote main branch. Here's what I've already done:

```
git remote add origin <url>
git remote -v
git push origin master:main
```

I got the following error

```
! [rejected] master->main (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to '<url>'
```

Whenever I try to run

```
git push origin main
```

I get

```
Everything up-to-date
```

However, when I check the github repo, none of the changes have been pushed to the main branch. I have no idea how to push the changes and I don't want to do anything irrational on my own. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try pulling the remote main branch to your local master branch first, this will ensure it's completely up to date, and then you should be able to push it back.

```
git pull origin master
git push origin master:main
```